# Smoking and a burning

Tags: riddle

Here is a short, simple riddle.

> I smoke, but have no flame.
>
> I burn, but have no heat.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Dry ice

I smoke, but have no flame.

> Dry ice is a cold dense white mist

I burn, but have no heat.

> It has lower temperature than water ice, its temperature can give you freeze burns

Answer (score 4):

Copying and pasting it into Google gives the answer:

> ICE

[LINK](http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?op=2&id=660&comm=0)

Comment: It should be rather dry ice or solid carbon dioxide

Answer (score 2):

May be

> Ice

I smoke but have no flame

> You can see the smoke coming from ice(vapours)

I burn, but have no heat

> No heat but it melts

EDIT: Dont knew it can be found on google